# Django - ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python-3.x, django

Learning Django with tutorial and have error.

`File "F:\Python\COTSW\teashop\main\views.py", line 98, in cart_list total_amt+=int(item['qty'])*float(item['price'])`

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`

Views.py

```
def cart_list(request):
    total_amt = 0
    for p_id, item in request.session['cartdata'].items():
        total_amt+=int(item['qty'])*float(item['price'])
    return render(request, 'cart.html', {'cart_data': request.session['cartdata'], 'totalitems': len(request.session['cartdata']), 'total_amt': total_amt})
```

product.html

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <p>{{data.detail}}</p>
            <hr/>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <h6>Цена</h6>
                    <h6>&#x20BD <span class="product-price-{{data.id}}">{{data.price}}</span></h6>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr/>
            <div class="input-group my-3" style="width:30%;">
              <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control product-qty-{{data.id}}" id="productQty" />
              <div class="input-group-append">
                  <input type="hidden" class="product-id-{{data.id}}" value="{{data.id}}" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="product-title-{{data.id}}" value="{{data.title}}" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="product-image-{{data.id}}" value="{{data.image}}" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="product-price-{{data.id}}" value="{{data.price}}" />
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-to-cart" data-index="{{data.id}}" type="button" id="addToCartBtn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> В корзину</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Custom.js

```
$(document).on('click', ".add-to-cart", function(){
        var _vm=$(this);
        var _index=_vm.attr('data-index');
        var _qty = $(".product-qty-"+_index).val();
        var _productId = $(".product-id-"+_index).val();
        var _productTitle = $(".product-title-"+_index).val();
        var _productImage = $(".product-image-"+_index).val();
        var _productPrice = $(".product-price-"+_index).text();
        var _productSlug = $(".product-slug-"+_index).val();
        console.log(_productPrice)
        // Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url:'/add-to-cart',
            data:{
                'qty':_qty,
                'id':_productId,
                'title':_productTitle,
                'image':_productImage,
                'price':_productPrice,
                'slug':_productSlug,
            },
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend:function(){
                _vm.attr('disabled', true);
            },
            success:function(res){
                $(".cart-list").text(res.totalitems);
                _vm.attr('disabled',false);
            }
        });
```

Before changes `var _productPrice = $(".product-price").text();` was `var _productPrice = $(".product-price").text();`  and worked. Console.log showing correct price 500.00, but `total_amt+=int(item['qty'])*float(item['price'])` taking an empty string.

Everything works correctly in the tutorial and I don't understand what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I have an additional file for button "Load More". And it have different code.

ajax/product_list.py

```
<div class="card shadow">
  <a href="/product/{{product.slug}}/{{product.id}}"><img src="/media/{{product.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{product.title}}"></a>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-text"><a href="/product/{{product.slug}}/{{product.id}}">{{product.title}}</a></h5>
    <h6>&#x20BD {{product.price}}</h6>
```

I changed it to:

```
<div class="card shadow">
      <a href="/product/{{product.id}}"><img width="100" src="/media/{{product.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{product.title}}"></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-text"><a href="/product/{{product.id}}">{{product.title}}</a></h6>
        <h6>&#x20BD <span class="product-price-{{product.id}}">{{product.price}}</span></h6>
      </div>
```

like in main file, and this is helped. Yes, I'm stupid, looked error in wrong place.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `item["price"]` is an empty string, also the problem maybe that value is not coming to the server from javascript, you can check it whether it's a empty string or not as:

```py
def cart_list(request):
    total_amt = 0
    for p_id, item in request.session['cartdata'].items():
        qty = int(item['qty'])
        price = item['price']
        if price:
            price = float(price)
            total_amt += qty * price
        else:
            # Handle empty price value (e.g. display an error message)
            pass
    return render(request, 'cart.html', {'cart_data': request.session['cartdata'], 'totalitems': len(request.session['cartdata']), 'total_amt': total_amt})
```

Try checking this, if its an empty string then some problem with javascript code i.e. numeric value of price is not coming to the server.

Comment: Yes, it sends an empty string and I understand that, but I don't understand why? And your code working to show result with no price.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the jQuery to read the value of the hidden input field and not “text”.

```
var _productPrice = $(".product-price-"+_index).text();
```

should be

```
var _productPrice = $(".product-price-"+_index).val();
```

Comment: I had `.val` before `.text`, but with `.val`, even `console.log()` doesn't take the price

Comment: You should use a unique id, not class, in the input field. With the class, jQuery finds also the text in <h6> tag in the table and returns that when you select .text().